# Грамотна ли фраза?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"И тогда нам ничего не будет страшно". Можно так сказать или коряво звучит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Звучит... И употребляется не только Вами, но и известными авторами. Но, когда начинаешь разбирать предложение, понимаешь, что местоимение должно быть в именительном падеже. Ничто не страшно (предикативная основа). Если поставить родительный падеж, то вопрос от предиката не страшно ну никак не задается! Поискала в справочниках. Нашла в словаре грамматических вариантов (Академия наук. Институт русского языка. 2007 год) указание на разговорный характер данной конструкции. Поэтому исходите из речевой ситуации при выборе нужного варианта.

Answer (score 0):

Все вполне читабельно, слух не режет.